# How to test events generated from node.js http request?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have a node.js code that I'm testing with mocha and sinon

```
var request = require('request');
request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
  /* code I already tested */
})
.on('error', function(err) {
  /* code I want to test */
})
```

I have created a stub with sinon `var requestGet = sinon.stub(request, 'get');` and I created different units to test the `/* code I already tested */`

Now I want to test the code `/* code I want to test */` executed when `request.get()` emit an `error` event but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make your own `EventEmitter`, stub the `.get` method and use it however you want. You'll be able to emit any events:

```js
//Stubbing
emitter = new EventEmitter();
sandbox.stub(request, 'get').returns(emitter);

//And when you need to fire the event:
emitter.emit('error', new Error('critical error'));
```

Here is an example.

Say you have a method `makeRequest`. And you want to test that in case of critical error the application must be stopped by calling `application.stop()`.

Here is how you could test it (please see my comments):

```js
const request = require('request');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const assert = require('assert');
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

const application = { stop () { console.log('appliation is stopped') } };

const makeRequest = () => {
    return request
        .get('http://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) { return console.error(error); }

            console.log('executed');
        })
        .on('error', err => {
            if (err.message === 'critical error') {
                application.stop();
            }
        });
}

describe('makeRequest', () => {
    let emitter;

    let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    let stopSpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Using our own emitter. We'll be able to raise any events.
        emitter = new EventEmitter();

        // We don't want the standard `get` logic to be executed as we are testing the error only.
        // Notice - we are returning `emitter` so the .on method exists.
        sandbox.stub(request, 'get').returns(emitter);

        stopSpy = sandbox.spy(application, 'stop');
    });


    it('should stop the app in case of a critical error', () => {
        // No need to worry about the callbacks, the stubbed method is sync.
        makeRequest();

        // Now emitting the error.
        emitter.emit('error', new Error('critical error'));

        // Checking if the required method has been called.
        assert.equal(stopSpy.calledOnce, true);
    });

    afterEach(() => sandbox.restore());
})
```

Comment: just out of curiosity why are you using `.callsFake(() => emitter);` instead of `.returns(() => emitter);` ?

Comment: @Edo Hm... :) That's just a habit. `.returns` looks better, I'll edit the answer.